# ¿Por qué al intentar elevar a una potencia un número me sale error?

Tags: c++

El problema es que intente crear un programa para poder realizar mi tarea más fácil, pero me encontré con un problema en mi programa, cuando elevo un numero a una potencia me salen números extremadamente largos o aparece que el resultado es 0, cosa que no tiene ningún sentido.
Estoy haciendo el programa en Dev-C++ y me sería de mucha ayuda que alguien me ayude con este problema. dejo el código a continuación:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    char c1, c2, c3;
    double num1, num2, num3, operacion1, operacion2;
    cout<< "Programa para terminar esta tarea" <<endl;
    cout<<"========================================================================================" <<endl;
    cout<< "Carretera == c " <<endl ;
    cout<< "Edificio == e " <<endl ;
    cout<<"========================================================================================" <<endl;
    cout<< "Eligeeeeeeeeeee: " ;
    cin >> c1 ;
    switch (c1) {
        //case c me funcona de maravilla.
    case 'c':
        cout<<"========================================================================================" <<endl;
        cout<< "cantidad de metros que mide la calle 1: " <<endl;
        cin>> num1 ;
        cout<<"cantidad de metros que mide la calle 2: " <<endl;
        cin>> num2 ;
        cout<<"========================================================================================" <<endl;
        operacion1 = num1+num2 ;
        operacion2 = sqrt (pow (num1, 2) + pow (num2, 2)) ;
        cout<<"la distancia de la calle 3 son : " <<operacion2 <<" metros" <<endl;
        cout<< "La distancia de la calle 1 y la calle 2 son : " <<operacion1 << " metros" <<endl; 
        if (operacion1 > operacion2)
        {
            cout<< "La ruta que recorre menos distancia es calle 3"<<endl;
            cout<<"========================================================================================" <<endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<< "La ruta que recorre menos distancia es calle 1 y 2" <<endl;
            cout<<"========================================================================================" <<endl;
        }
        break;
        //El error parece estar en case e
    case 'e':
        cout<<"========================================================================================" <<endl;
        cout<< "cantidad de metros que mide la hipotenusa: " <<endl;
        cin>> num1 ;
        cout<<"cantidad de metros que mide el cateto inferior: " <<endl;
        cin>> num2 ;
        cout << "cantidad de metros que mide el cateto inferior" <<endl ;
        cin>> num3 ;
        cout<<"========================================================================================" <<endl;
        operacion1 == sqrt(pow(num1, 2) - pow(((num3-num2)/2), 2));
        cout<< "La altura del edificio es de: " <<operacion2 <<" metros" <<endl;
        break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas son las cosas que noté:

1:

```
//Estás pidiendo dos veces el cateto inferior
cout<<"cantidad de metros que mide el cateto inferior: " <<endl;
cin>> num2 ;
cout << "cantidad de metros que mide el cateto inferior" <<endl;
```

2:

```
//Aquí estás comparando los valores en vez de asignar a la variable.
//Deberías usar un solo signo igual
operacion1 == sqrt(pow(num1, 2) - pow(((num3-num2)/2), 2));

//En la linea anterior asignas el resultado a operacion1 pero aquí imprimes operacion2 que no está inicializada.
cout<< "La altura del edificio es de: " <<operacion2 <<" metros" <<endl;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me percaté de esos errores <3

Comment: @Randal No hay problema :) Si no tienes más dudas por favor recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta.

Comment: Una buena respuesta brinda una explicación. Puede que otras personas no se den cuenta de lo que está mal.

Comment: @Mateo cierto pero al mismo tiempo esta pregunta no es en general. Es especificamente sobre el caso de Randal. De todos modos puedo agregar una pequeña explicación